# How can I override JavaScript code injected by my CMS

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-events

I want to override a hover event written by Drupal menu. Because I am unable to modify the code written by Drupal, I'd like to know how I can view it and then override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view how the code works by inspecting the JavaScript includes in the page... I imagine with a CMS like Drupal though, with JavaScript built ontop of jQuery, trying to find exactly where this event is being added will resemble looking for a needle in a haystack.

---

Whilst `$('selector').off('eventName');` will work in the basic case (i.e. if an event handler is attached *directly* to the element), it won't work in the situation where the handler is bound to an ancestor.

To easiest way to fix this is to add your *own* event to the element and use [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop event handlers firing that have been bound to ancestors.

```
$('selector').off('eventName').on('eventName', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

... a shorthand for this is to pass `false` instead of `function`:

```
$('selector').off('eventName').on('eventName', false);
```

For more info see [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `events` object to see what events are attached to an object:

```
$('selector').data('events')
```

Or you can just remove the jQuery event all together:

```
$('selector').off('eventName');
```

Comment: Note for future-proofing: `data('events')` will [no longer works in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#data-events-) without the migrate plugin.